# access my work network from home PC

Tags: networking, vpn

I would like to be able to access my work network without taking my work laptop home. I can do this hit-and-miss with go-to-my-pc or other similar means but would like to not have to use those services. When I use the VPN information that allows access using my work laptop on my home laptop I get an error saying I don't have permission. I believe this is a work domain issue but can it be resolved?

Comment: Have you asked your work's IT department about it? They would much better know how to fix it than we do.

Comment: Not only would they know better, they would also know what's allowed. It's a good idea to check with them either way.

Comment: Can be a VERY fast route to losing your job.

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard way to do what you are inquiring about, and that's by means of a "reverse tunnel". If you are on windows, the application of choice is Putty, and you find a good guide to that [here](http://www.smythies.com/~doug/network/reverse_ssh_tunnel/index.html). If instead you are on a *Nix machine (including Mac) then openssh is your app, and you can find many guides all over the Net.

Basically, this assumes that you can connect from work to home, but not viceversa, and that's most likely correct because at home you are probably sole manager of your network, while at work, in most cases, there are some IT guys in charge of it. If you use "cryptographic keys" instead of passwords, the application is also very secure (I do not know exactly about Putty, but OpenSSH, like everything coming from the OpenBSD guys, is essentially bug-free). The set-up of a reverse tunnel is not difficult, but it requires a minimum of work, so I suggest you look up the Web site
above.

Lastly, there is now also a useful third-party application for Putty called MyEnTunnel (you may [look it up here](http://nemesis2.qx.net/pages/MyEnTunnel) which is capable of restarting the "reverse tunnel" from work if it gets disconnected for no matter which reason, so that you may essentially leave it unattended for weeks or months. *Nix users (again including Mac OsX) have the same facility thru a package called autossh. The combination of autossh/MyETunnel and Putty/OpenSSH basically make for an unassailable, forever-ready connection.

EDIT: at the strong urging of Tanner, I would like to point out that this is a technical solution. Whether this is also a good solution, from a non-technical point of view, is a matter to be discussed (and agreed upon) with members of your work's IT dept.

Comment: Not a good idea to do this at work without permission from the IT department.

Comment: And pray, who suggested as much?

Comment: What? You suggested it.

Comment: Where???? Please point to the exact spot where I suggested it.

Comment: Take a look at the big red arrows: http://i.imgur.com/Zr6vtlH.png. _That's_ where you suggested something that wouldn't be a good idea without permission from the IT department.

Comment: ...You realize you're going to trigger the automatic vote fraud detection now, right?

Comment: I'll take my chance, Tanner, seeing the quality of your evidence I don't think I am running much of a risk.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10954/discussion-between-tanner-and-mariusmatutiae)